# Can someone give me a concrete example of an induced representation?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

I've been given the definition

> Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $W$ is a representation of $H$, then the induced representation $\mathrm{Ind}^G_H(W) = \mathcal{F}(G, W)^H$ is a representation of $G$.

but am struggling to understand it. Here, suppose that $X$ is a finite set and $W$ is a $k$-vector space, then $\mathcal{F}(X, W) = \{f : X \to W\}$, is the $k$-vector space of functions $X$ to $W$.

For example, can you give me a nice, two dimensional, say, representation of some nice finite group $H$, where I can see where every element $h \in H$ maps to as a matrix in the general linear group, and explain how to construct the induced representation of $G$?

Comment: Try this. Let $H\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ be a cyclic group whose action on $W=\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$ is to swap the two standard basis elements. Then what is the induced representation $Ind_H^G(W)$ where $H\hookrightarrow G\cong \mathbb{Z}_4$ makes $H$ the unique cyclic group of order $2$.